# NextJS / next-translate : get lang outside of components

Tags: reactjs, next.js, lang

We have a short question for our application (NextJS 11.0.0 + next-translate 1.0.7)
The library contains a function to make an API call (/lib/mylib.js) :

```
export const getDataExample = async (lang) => {
    return fetch(_apiurl_/example/{lang});
};
```

And my component in react (/components/myComponent.js) call this function with a useEffect:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import useTranslation          from 'next-translate/useTranslation';
import { getDataExample }      from '/lib/mylib';
export default function MyComponent() {
    const [data, setData] = useState(false);
    const { lang }        = useTranslation();
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const response = await getDataExample(lang);
            setData(response);
        };
        fetchData();
    }, []);
    [...]
}
```

I don't want to call getDataExample() directly with the lang parameter.
Is it possible to get the current language in the function (/lib/mylib.js) ?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your reply !
But now imagine that my library (/lib/mylib.js) is also used to fetch data into a getServerSideProps :

```
export async function getServerSideProps({ locale }) {
    const response = await getDataExample(locale);
    
    [...]
}
```

React Hooks are not available here, so what do you do ?

Answer (score -1):

You can create your custom hook. This is an example:

```
const useFetchWithLang = (func) => {
    const { lang } = useTranslation()
    return useCallback((args) => func({ ...args, lang }), [lang])
}
```

```
const fetchDataExample = ({ otherParam, lang }) => {
  return { test: 'test1' }
}
const fetchDataExampleWithLang = useFetchWithLang(fetchDataExample)
```

After for example, you could use it in a useEffect.

```
useEffect(() => {
   const fetchData = async () => {
      const response = await fetchDataExampleWithLang({ otherParam: 'test' });
      setData(response);
   };
   fetchData();
}, []);
```